# How to get results from requesting permissions in GoogleSignIn in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with getting results from **GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions()** method. I am asking user for hydration data permission. This code is inside button ***onClick*** scope.

```
    val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HYDRATION, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HYDRATION, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
    .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_HYDRATION, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
    .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_HYDRATION, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
    .build()

val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(context, fitnessOptions)

if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, fitnessOptions)) {
    GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
        activity,
        GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
        account,
        fitnessOptions)
} else {
    // we have access ...
}
```

So I found the way, that in compose we have to use **rememberLauncherForActivityResult** in order to get results for our activity.

```
val resultLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { activityResult->
    if (activityResult.resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        Log.d("appDebug", "Accepted")
    else {
        Log.d("appDebug", "Denied")
    }
}
```

Unfortunetly this isn't working with google permissions, because I can't create an intent. How should I handle this in jetpack compose? Documentation mentions only old deprecated onActivityResult for UI toolkit.

Comment: Have you checked [Accompanist Permissions](https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/)?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Yes and it doesn't cover this specific case.

Comment: onActivityResult may be deprecated but it works fine. It has been around since the beginning of Android and isn't going away, so use it.

Comment: @Johann it can't be used with GoogleSignIn in jetpack compose.

Comment: I'm using OneTap Google sign in on my Compose app using onActivityResult.

Comment: My bad I meant google permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same use case. I solve it via this approach -

```
val startForResult =
                    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
                        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            viewModel.uiState.value.isGoogleFitConnected=true
                        }
                    }

val googleSignIn =
                   GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                   .addExtension(fitnessOptions)
                   .build()

val intent = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, googleSignIn)
                        startForResult.launch(intent.signInIntent)
```

Check [this tutorial](https://github.com/AseemWangoo/hands_on_kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/aseemwangoo/handsonkotlin/auth/view/AuthView.kt) code snippet for more details.

Comment: I did a little workaround for this problem, but your solution works!